# TextBox does not update in MvvmLight

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, visual-studio-2013, mvvm-light

I'm writing a demo program using MvvmLight.What I want is binding a TextBox in the `View` to a property in the `Model`.The binding seems right,for I can show my input in the TextBox by a MessageBox.The problem is that after setting the property to string.Empty in the `ViewModel`,the textbox in the `View` remains unchanged.

`Model`:*LoginToMisInfo.cs*

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;

namespace MvvmLight1.Model
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class contains properties that a View can data bind to.
    /// <para>
    /// See http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm
    /// </para>
    /// </summary>
    public class LoginToMisInfo : ViewModelBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the LoginToMisInfo class.
        /// </summary>
        public LoginToMisInfo()
        {
        }
        private string userName;

        public string UserName
        {
            get
            {
                return userName;
            }
            set
            {
                userName = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`ViewModel`:*LoginToMis.cs*

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using MvvmLight1.Model;
using System.ComponentModel;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows;

namespace MvvmLight1.ViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class contains properties that a View can data bind to.
    /// <para>
    /// See http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm
    /// </para>
    /// </summary>
    public class LoginToMis : ViewModelBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the LoginToMis class.
        /// </summary>
        public LoginToMis()
        {
            //CommandCancel = new RelayCommand(() => ConfirmExecute(), () => true);
            CommandConfirm = new RelayCommand(() => ConfirmExecute(), () => true);
            CommandClear = new RelayCommand(() => ClearExecuate(), () => true);
        }

        LoginToMisInfo LoginInfo = new LoginToMisInfo();
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string UserName
        {
            get
            {
                return LoginInfo.UserName;
            }
            set
            {
                LoginInfo.UserName = value;
                if(this.PropertyChanged!=null)
                {
                    this.PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LoginInfo.UserName"));
                }
            }
        }

        public ICommand CommandCancel { get; private set; }
        public ICommand CommandConfirm { get; private set; }
        public ICommand CommandClear { get; private set; }

        private void ConfirmExecute()
        {
            MessageBox.Show(UserName);
        }

        private void ClearExecuate()
        {
            UserName = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

`View`:

`DataContext`

```
DataContext="{Binding MyLoginToMis, Source={StaticResource Locator}
```

(I've registered `LoginToMis` in the `ViewModelLocator`)

`TextBox`

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
MinWidth="100" 
Text="{Binding UserName,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

'Button'

```
<Button Content="Confirm" MinWidth="150" MinHeight="80"
Margin="50,0,50,0" IsDefault="True" 
Command="{Binding CommandConfirm}"/>

<Button Content="Clear" MinWidth="150" MinHeight="80"
Margin="50,0,50,0" Command="{Binding CommandClear}"/>
```

So basically,I create a class in the `Model`,and wrap a instance of it in the `ViewModel`,then I bind the property in the `ViewModel` to the TextBox in the `View`.After entering some words in the TextBox and click **Confirm**,a MessageBox will pop up and show the inputs in the TextBox.Clicking **Clear**,however,the TextBox do not update.Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should raise property changed notification for `UserName` property instead.

And you can use `RaisePropertyChanged` method provided by `MvvmLight` to raise property changed notification. The method available from `ViewModelBase` class which inherits `ObservableObject` :

```
RaisePropertyChanged("UserName");
```

Comment: You can use `RaisePropertyChanged` method provided by MVVMLight to raise property changed notification. The method available from `ViewModelBase` class which inherits `ObservableObject`

Comment: +1 For RaisePropertyChanged,It works,though I'm curious about the difference between `PropertyChanged` and `RaisePropertyChanged`.